# is patternmatching function in python relevant for answer evaluating system?

Tags: python, nlp

I'm developing a system for conducting online examinations that evaluate students answers compared to the teacher's reference answer. Currently, I have pattern matching in python compares two texts and generates a value between `0` and `1`. is there any other efficient method to do this like NLP functions???

Comment: The question in your title does not seem to match the question in your post. Please clarify. Are you asking "Is pattern matching relevant?" or "is there an efficient way to do pattern matching?"?

Comment: To get a useful response to this, you'll need to be more specific about what kind of "pattern matching" you want. Do you just need a regular expression or even simple string operations to look for certain terms/phrases? Or are you trying to do something with machine learning models? If so, what exactly? What is the "pattern matching" that you already have?